# django rest framework post data with foreign key

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='catalog')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Sum,Count

class CatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # company_details = CompanyData(many=True)
    total_pieces = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # company = CompanySerializer(source='company_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = ('name','no_of_pcs','per_piece_price','company_name','total_pieces','total_price')
        depth = 1

    def get_total_pieces(self, obj):
        totalpieces = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_pieces=Count('no_of_pcs'))
        return totalpieces["total_pieces"]

    def get_total_price(self, obj):
        totalprice = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_price=Sum('per_piece_price'))
        return totalprice["total_price"]


    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(CatalogSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['catalog'] = instance.name
        return rep
```

here is my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets

class CatalogView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Catalog.objects.select_related('company_name')
    serializer_class = CatalogSerializer
```

[image: ff]

i wants to choose company for each catalog.which is defined as foreignkey

please check the screen shot i have shared.
here no fields is coming for company.
i wants to post company along with all fields of catalog.
here i have shared the screen shot of input fields.
thanks,,

Comment: i want writable nested serializers.

Comment: you can do it from the tab `raw data`

Comment: could you please explan??

Comment: try to search, you create many question at the moment witout self research.